# How can I tell the render engine to use my "$user" explicitly?

Tags: drupal, render

In Drupal 6, I want to pass a parameter named `$user` to a PHP template to render. However, the render engine always treats `$user` as the global one.

Is there any way to tell the render engine to use my `$user` explicitly?

Comment: Why not just call your variable `$account` or something else so you can distinguish? This is how core Drupal usually handles that

Answer (score 0):

try this: `$user->name;`

or in function:

```
<?php
function get_username() {
    global $user;
    print $user->name;
    exit();
  }
?>
```